# Mimic Macs CTRL + ARROW behavior on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, shortcuts

I would like to mimic the behavior of Mac's `ctrl` + `<arrow key>` on Windows 10. Particularly for the left/right arrow keys. To describe the behavior briefly for anyone who doesn't know. Say in Mac you have the following full screen windows:

```
Desktop | Full-screen Window 1 | Full-screen Window 2 | ... | Full-screen Window N
```

If your *active* window (the window currently displayed) is `Window 2` pressing `ctrl` + `left arrow` will switch your active window to window 1, pressing it again will switch to the Desktop. Pressing `ctrl` + `right arrow` will switch back to window 1 and again back to window 2. This is similar to Windows 10's alt-tab behavior with the key difference being that the order of the windows is preserved on Mac, while on windows, it is reordered by most-recent window.

I have also discovered the `ALT`+`ESC` and `ALT`+`SHIFT`+`ESC` keyboard shortcuts from [this](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/358) github post. This functionality is more similar to the Mac's in that order is preserved, but it is confusing that the order is different from the windows 10 task bar's order and also spans across all monitors. So if the `ALT`+`ESC` order of the windows would be window 1, window 2, ..., window n, the order of the windows in the task bars might be something like: (With the `Combine taksbar buttons` set to `Never` and `Show Taskbar buttons on` set to `Taskbar where window is open` in the `Taskbar` settings page)

Monitor 1: `Desktop | Window 2`

Monitor 2: `Desktop | window 3 | Window 1 | Window 4`

This makes switching unintuitive.

**Side note**:
If it is not possible to mimic this behavior out of the box or with existing 3rd party software, I'd be interested in being pointed to any way to programmatically get/set the active window, as then I could just write a script and map it to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: There is a PC Magazine article out since May 27, 2020 which may help you https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-remap-your-keyboard Have a nice evening. ;-)

Comment: @vssher I should have cleared this up in my post, but I am not trying to use `ctrl`+`arrow` specifically, but rather look for a corresponding shortcut in windows. The similar keyboard shortcuts in windows that I know about are `alt`+`tab` and `alt`+`esc`. That key-mapping is fine, I don't have a problem with that, but rather the behavior of these shortcuts are slightly different on windows.